# Excel - Categorize lines of data based on 3 variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following problem:
[image: Sample]

I have two sheets in the excel file that are included in this problem.

The first sheet contains the constraints for each group and is the first part of the picture.

The group “Correct 1” is a group where following restrictions are met:

“value 1” is between 0-1000

“value 2” is between 0-2000

“value 3” is between 0-500

_

The second sheet contains the data I want to label with the correct group based on the three values (1, 2 & 3).

For example:

The row labeled “info1” has three values connected to it.

value 1 = 321  “Correct 1” & “Correct 2”

Value 2 = 2005  “Correct 2”, “Correct 3” & “Error”

Value 3 = 400   “Correct 1”, “Correct 2” & “Error”

The Info1 line will therefore be labeled “Correct 2” since that group applies to all values.

Is this possible?
Formula or VBA are both fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(B2<1001,IF(C2<2001,"Correct 1","Correct 2"),IF(D2<401,"Error","Correct 3"))`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you for the effort, Pqqwetiqe :) 
I may not have been totally clear though since my dataset is too large for these simple If formulas. my first sheet containing the constraints is 250 rows long. So what I'm looking for is maybe some sort of array formula?